# Get .each on every html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want in my foreach loop in my View (MVC) every button to work, that is, to render a partial view. But only the first button works (rendering the partial view), not the rest. I have not bothered to paste the code from my view, since it's just a div with the code for rendering the partial view.

Here is the code and what I had in mind:

```
<button class="myBtn btn btn-default"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.Id })'">
   Edit
</button>
```

Javascript (taken from w3schools with slight modifications):

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

$(btn).each(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++)
    {
        //btn[i].className = "myBtn";
        btn = btn[i];
    }
});

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";        
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: `$(btn).each(function () {` is already a loop. I don't think you need a `for` loop within it as well. Look up the syntax of the callback function supplied to .each - you can pass in parameters, once of which will represent the button in that iteration. https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Also `btn.onclick ` won't work on a collection, you need to assign onclick to each button individually (or, since you have jQuery, do it using jQuery syntax (e.g. `$(btn).click(function(e) { .... });` which will do it on all of them. https://api.jquery.com/click/. However, your markup already defines a onclick which navigates to another page? Are you intending to remove that?

Comment: It seems to work now by your help (I changed to jQuery .click(), but now the partialview disappears as soon as I hit the button, because it goes to the action and I don't know what to do over there to get that partial view still stay after taking the id from the action?

Comment: Your buttons have `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.Id })'"` as an additional "click" event, which will cause them navigate to another page when clicked. Is it the case that you are you really wanting to load that "Edit" view into the modal, via ajax? It's not entirely clear, from your description, what the modal is meant to contain.

Comment: Yes, when I click the button, I want it to fetch the edit thing I want to edit from db, then after that, load that partial view (to make changes in that popup). But now, as you mentioned, and in addition to that, I get a quick view of the partial view, then it disappears because it goes to the controller and action.

Comment: ok so it sounds like firstly you need to remove that "onclick" from the button tag definition. Then you can either a) load the whole partial view via ajax into your modal as a complete HTML snippet (you just pass to the controller the ID of the item you want to edit), or fetch some JSON via ajax representing the model data, which you then assign to the necessary fields in the modal yourself, using JavaScript. The first approach is probably easier. Do you know how to make a request to a controller action via ajax? There are lots of examples online, if not.

Comment: Well, for the easier way, if there is, I had in mind to just route the url from the button click to the Edit page, and then pass along the html attribute of the button, if that is possible, like Value="@item.Id". Can this be done, so as to speak, not going via an action, but as soon as the button is clicked, I route it, or just direct it to the edit page along with the id?

And if you know some ajax, perhaps you can provide an easy example doing what you just said, because I don't know almost anything about ajax.

Comment: Yeah you could do that, but in that case what would be the purpose of your modal?

Comment: The modal would render the partial view of the edit page. So this edit page would be a partial view (the modal that pop ups).

Comment: But if you  "direct it to the edit page along with the id" as you describe, that involves going to another web page entirely, right? So it can't possibly involve a modal on the current page, because the current page no longer exists once you go to the Edit page.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, and pardon me for being unclear, if there is a way, to just redirect the button to the edit partial page along with an id, or the model (item) without passing an action?

Comment: "without passing an action"...sorry but what do you mean by this exactly? If you want to redirect to another page, you need a URL. In MVC, the action methods are the endpoints which are accessed via a URL. The safest way to generate the correct URL for any given controller action method is to use the Url.Action helper method to create it. Let's try and be clearer...do you want this Edit form to open as a modal _within the current page_, or do you want it to open _on its own in a new page_? Those are basically your two options, with different implementations. I can't work out what you want

Comment: I want my edit page (or edit form) to open in an existing page, as a modal page. So when I click the edit button, on that same page, I want this edit form open up as a modal, and this edit form page, is a partial view.

Because, when I click on the edit button, the modal page comes up, but it disappears, because I have an onclick in that button which points to an action through the `@Url.Action` helper, because I need to pass the id or the item into the modal page (edit form button).

Answer (score 0):

when you in loop then you changed the your "btn" array look below code

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");
console.log(btn);
```

this output should be array like this [image]

```
$(btn).each(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++)
    {
        //btn[i].className = "myBtn";
        btn = btn[i];
```

When you set your array output and loop changed by you and you can see this image what happened [image] this below console.log output, you changed your array and couldn't walk each btn object in your code

```
        console.log(i)
    }
});
console.log(btn);
```